# String Format as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

In a school assignment, we have this example:

[image: image here]

It tells me to create a `public abstract method` called `ToString` with a string format parameter, which returns a `string`. How is this possible?

I tried this:

```
public abstract string ToString(String.Format type)
{
    return "Some text";
}
```

But it returned a number of errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Format' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
'Shape.ToString(string, Format)' cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `abstract` method can't have body.. `public abstract string ToString(String.Format type);` only will valid.

Comment: Along with what @BagusTesa said the parameter is named format but is type `string` in your image. So it would be `public abstract string ToString(string format);`

Comment: good effort but youve just misread the spec +1 for trying

Comment: @WhatsThePoint oh haha, yes I totally did. Not used to read C# from that structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method should look like:

```
public abstract string ToString(string format);
```

You missreaded the specification. Your image shows a `ToString` method with a `string` parameter of name format.

Have a look at the [MSDN string.format page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) to get more information about format strings in C#.

To get more information about abstract you can have a look at the [MSDN abstract page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sf985hc5.aspx).

Comment: Yeah okay, but doesn't the image tell me that it returns a string? e.g. ToString(string format):string(this)

Comment: Oh hehe, do I feel like a noob. Okay, great, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you are misreading the spec. It has a parameter of type string with name format. ie

```
public abstract string ToString(string format);
```

Note the second error which says that you need to not have a body for a method marked as abstract. You can provide an implementation there if you want but in that case you'd want to mark it as `virtual` rather than `abstract`.

Comment: Yeah okay, but doesn't the image tell me that it returns a string? e.g. ToString(string format):string(this)

Comment: @Jesper, in the spec it had `ToString(string **format**):string`